# Not able to run Jmeter tests for Third party (Signicat) SSO login

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, performance-testing, bankid

I am trying to run performance test using Jmeter for my client application which uses Signicat, a third part identity verification site for SSO login. I cannot get through with jmeter execution for login. There is a dynamic token appended in one of the http requests related to login but I cannot find it in any of the previous responses to correlate.

Has anybody tried Performance tests with Signicat or any other SSO login ? I appreciate any suggestions or leads. Thank you.

PS: I tried to monitor the traffic in fiddler while accessing the site . I don't see the token source there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question doesn't contain sufficient level of details.

If you're seeing the dynamic token there are following possible options:

1. It needs to be **correlated** (extracted from the previous response), the possible sources are:

   - URL (as a part of a [redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections))
   - response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header)
   - response body
2. It needs to be **generated**, if the dynamic value is being generated by client-side JavaScript JMeter won't be able to execute the JavaScript, you will have to replicate the code using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and preferably [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as the language in order to generate the same value as the real browser does

Looking into [Connecting your application](https://documentation.signicat.nl/connectis-identity-broker/connecting-your-application) chapter there are several possible protocols/options and it will require rather a story than a chapter to provide comprehensive instructions on each of them:

[image]

for some of them like "Other third party software" it is not even possible doing this remotely without knowing the infrastructure and the authentication/authorization processes.